# woocommerce-how to select value from dropdown that contains attribute values

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a variable product. The product page contains a dropdown with the values of the product's custom attribute. I would like to pass a GET parameter to the page, and set the dropdown's selected value to the value of the GET parameter. How do I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add the name parameter of the select input and set it equal to the value you'd like to pre-select.

For example, a product taxonomy of color with a red attribute:

`http://www.example.com/product/your-product?pa_color=red`